# Can't install python adb - M2Crypto Error

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I've tried to install python adb.

With pip and legacy install I get the same error.

```
Writing C:\Users\ARAJO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-q9rc0j_2\M2Crypto-

0.26.4\setup.cfg
Running M2Crypto-0.26.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\ARAJO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-q9rc0j_2\M2Crypto-0.26.4\egg-dist-tmp-tf0svopa
_m2crypto_wrap.c
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(3550): warning C4068: unknown pragma
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(3551): warning C4068: unknown pragma
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(3554): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/err.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

EDIT:

After cryptography install and config:
I got this errors, what can be the origin of this?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2448): note: see declaration of 'fdopen'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7653): error C2332: 'struct': missing tag name
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7653): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7653): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7653): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7654): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'tzp'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(7681): warning C4013: 'gettimeofday' undefined; assuming extern returning int
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9489): error C2037: left of 'num' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9509): error C2037: left of 'num' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9538): error C2037: left of 'data' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9558): error C2037: left of 'data' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9587): error C2037: left of 'sorted' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9607): error C2037: left of 'sorted' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9636): error C2037: left of 'num_alloc' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9656): error C2037: left of 'num_alloc' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9684): error C2037: left of 'comp' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9704): error C2037: left of 'comp' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9716): error C2027: use of undefined type 'stack_st'
C:\OpenSSL-win64\include\openssl/stack.h(17): note: see declaration of 'stack_st'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9947): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(9947): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10350): error C2037: left of 'stack' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10370): error C2037: left of 'stack' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10382): error C2027: use of undefined type 'stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING'
C:\OpenSSL-win64\include\openssl/safestack.h(151): note: see declaration of 'stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10430): error C2037: left of 'stack' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st_OPENSSL_BLOCK'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10450): error C2037: left of 'stack' specifies undefined struct/union 'stack_st_OPENSSL_BLOCK'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(10462): error C2027: use of undefined type 'stack_st_OPENSSL_BLOCK'
C:\OpenSSL-win64\include\openssl/safestack.h(159): note: see declaration of 'stack_st_OPENSSL_BLOCK'
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(19168): warning C4013: 'sslv3_method' undefined; assuming extern returning int
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(29537): error C2078: too many initializers
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(29443): warning C4113:
```

Is it related to the package?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to have OpenSSL include files and libraries, and you have to hint compiler where they are. See https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-windows

For example:

```
C:\> \path\to\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
C:\> set LIB=C:\OpenSSL-win64\lib;%LIB%
C:\> set INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-win64\include;%INCLUDE%
C:\> pip install cryptography
```